# Get scheduled rules in rule

Tags: 7, rules

I need to get the date of a scheduled rule and display it to the user.

I also would like (Not necessarily required, I can also use an invisible CCK field) to use the existence of this schedule as a condition in yet another rule.

Is it possible to get this using rules alone or do I need to use the "Execute custom PHP code" condition/action to find them?

Answer (score 0):

What about doing it the other way around? Use a [date](http://drupal.org/project/date) field and triggering the rule according to it?

Comment: Short version is that I require a fairly large set of conditions (however your answer has given me an idea, I could make another invisibile date field and fill it with the same value when the first rule is scheduled, but this is "yet more hax" and I'd rather have a clean implementation as it's pretty complicated allready)